# Python - Search plugin of Folium doesn't appear

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, geopandas, folium

I'm trying to reproduce the following jupyter notebook :

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jtbaker/folium/blob/geojsonmarker/examples/plugin-Search.ipynb

But once I'm trying to create the map I had to make a few changes to the search plugin because of the documentation:

```
citysearch = Search(layer=citygeo, 
                geom_type='Point', 
                placeholder="Search for a US City", 
                collapsed=True, 
                search_label='nameascii'
               ).add_to(m)
```

becomes, according to the folium documentation [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.Search) :

```
citysearch = Search(data=citygeo, 
                   geom_type='Point', 
                   search_label='nameascii'
                   ).add_to(m)
```

The issue is that, at best the search plugin doesn't appear and at worse my folium map isn't displayed. Does anyone have this problem as well ? Or is there any dependecies I've forgot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright found the solution after couple days of research,

The example in the notebook is using a new search.pyfile which isn't updated in the folium document yet (as the working version is from december 23 2018 so it's very recent)

I just went to the pluginfolder to change the search.py with the github newest version [Here](https://github.com/jtbaker/folium/blob/SearchRefactor/folium/plugins/search.py) Then it doesn't update automatically to my notebooks so I just created a new one and there it works !

OR simpler way : update folium to version 0.8.0 and it will work so just do `pip install folium==0.8.0` (just went out yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. When you press F12 in your browser, you'll see that there's an JS-error. I tried replacing `data=citygeo` by `data=citygeo.to_json()` - which will display your map - but still doesn't show the searchbox.

My guess it has something to do with a bug in the latest new version of Folium. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

Comment: After a few research, I understood that what was displayed in the tutorial was a development version and wasn't in the 0.7.0 package, you just need to update your folium package just like I explain in my answer and it shall work